# Don't show the data of my User table in View page source within Script tag

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I get the user data in script tag of my app.blade.php but when I view page resource show this line code.

' window.user = {"id":2,"name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com.af","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2021-03-02T04:52:43.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-02T04:52:43.000000Z"} '

unfortunately I don't want to show my data, how can i hide? any easy way....!?

this is my code in app.blade.php

```html
@auth
<script>
 window.user = @json(auth()->user())
</script>
@endauth
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another way to assign to your user variable e.g. store user to [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). The diffirent is it user data will be not in your code, it will be in your local storage, its able to view your user data as it was.

You can make it difficult to people to inspect to your code by encoding data like [BASE64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) before assign to your variable, then you decode its when you want to use it. that solution that can get your user data the same but it make more difficult to get it.